phpMyAdmin import CSV file fails
I am trying to import some data from a CSV file into an existing table in MySql database using phpMyAdmin. I’ve created and saved a CSV file GU_t_rf_imgTp.csv, here it is:

Now in phpMyAdmin I do:
First, I choose the table which to fill (in this case “GU_t_rf_img_type”). Then I click on the Import tab. Here I select the file, accept all the default settings, specify 1 query to skip (field names line), and click go.

All looks good, the top line message says “Import has been successfully finished, 6 queries executed. (GU_t_rf_imgTp.csv)”.

However when I go to Browse tab the table is empty:

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

I tried this on my system and it worked fine. Which MySQL or MariaDB version are you using, and which phpMyAdmin version? Could you also please tell us the data type for those columns or show the structure of the whole table?
